# Flutter google_sign_in cannot work on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have a Flutter project working on Swift project. I'm trying to integrate google_sign_in into this project, but it wants me to edit the ios/Runner/Info.plist file. I cannot edit this file because it is auto-generated in my project as .ios folder.

I tried editing the Info.plist file of the Swift project, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.